# translating linux build arguments to visual studio

Tags: linux, visual-studio-2008, build, compilation

How do linux compile style parameters translate to C++ (Visual Studio) compile parameters?

I have the string --enable-unicode-properties in a linux build script for C++ which I need to translate into visual studio.